# Constructing a triangle using heading and fixed distances?

Tags: math, vector, geometry, 2d

I want to construct a triangle in the real world to represent a 2D "viewing frustum" using the user's coordinates, heading (degrees currently facing from true north), and fixed distances that represent how far they can see.

I was imagining drawing a line of K1 distance from the user's point in the direction of the heading and marking a temporary point, then drawing a perpendicular line at that point to the previous line and marking 2 points on each side of the perpendicular line K2 distance away from the point.

This would give me the 3 points that I need. For those who are great at math, first is this possible and second can you give me some pointers on how to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In cartesian co-ordinates:

Assume:

- `+Y` axis is north.
- `K2` is distance from "temp point" to the two points you're creating
- Current position is `(Cx, Cy)`
- Heading `(H)` is angle clockwise from the Y-axis.
- Temporary point is `(Tx, Ty)`
- Remaining two points are `(Px, Py)` and `(Qx, Qy)`

Then:

```
Tx = Cx + K1 * sin(H)
Ty = Cy + K1 * cos(H)

Px = Tx - K2 * cos(H)
Py = Ty + K2 * sin(H)

Qx = Tx + K2 * cos(H)
Qy = Ty - K2 * sin(H)
```

When computing `(Tx, Ty)`, you use `sin(H)` with the x-coord and `cos(H)` with the y-coord because the angle is being measured from the Y-axis.  When computing `(Px, Py)` and `(Qx, Qy)` you use the fact that if `(a, b)` is some vector, then any multiple of `(-a, b)` is a vector perpendicular to the first.  Hence the `(sin(H), cos(H))` turns into `(-sin(H), cos(H))` and `(cos(H), -sin(H))`.  This falls out of the definition of dot product in 2-D cartesian space and the coordinate-free fact that the dot product of perpendicular vectors is zero.